# Rails 3: Storing boolean values as session key values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I'm using the active record store. I know usually session variables are strings, but I was wondering what the practices are for storing booleans or non string objects in the session? Does it work? And does it work for the cookie store? Is it frowned upon?

Thanks.

Comment: Why dont you try it out?

Comment: @Lichtamberg it worked for my active record store, but I don't really see anyone else doing it

Answer (score 1):

It works.

Its just a normal hash which is serialized.
You could just have tried it out.

Take care of the maximum size of cookies (i think it was about 4kbytes).